# Multiple date differences

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am new to SQL but I think I'm nearly there with this one. I have an ms access database with a table called SicknessLog. The fields are ID, StaffName, [Start/Return], Date.

When a member of staff is off work for sickness then a record is added to the table and the value in the [Start/Return] field is 1. When they return to work a new record is added with the same details except the [Start/Return] field is 0.

I am trying to write a query that shows the number of days between when a member of staff went sick ([Start/Return] value of -1) and when they returned to work ([Start/Return] value of 0)

So far I have this

```
SELECT [staffname], DATEDIFF("d", min([date]), max([date])) as [Days Sick]
FROM sicknesslog
WHERE [date] > (now()-30)
GROUP BY [staffname]
```

This shows how many days off each staff member has had in the last 30 days. The only problem I have is that it is also listing 0 days for staff who are currently away. If possible I would like it to show the number of days since they went sick up intil now for staff who have not returned.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Does [Date] ( a reserved word in Access) represent each day of the year or just when a person is sick?

Comment: what about staff members who have their absences ending within those 30 days but starting before this period? Using your query should also return 0... I can provide solution using `SQL Server` syntax so you can "translate" this in `MS Access`

Comment: Hi, The [date] field (square brackets due to being reserved word) is the date of that entry (when staff go sick or return from sickness.)  Yes, I also noticed the problem about staff who returned within last 30 days. I think I need to completely rewrite the query but not sure where to start

Comment: @MilenPavlov yea, SQL server solution would be a great start if you know it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT [staffname], DATEDIFF("d", min([date]), GETDATE()) as [Days Sick]
FROM sicknesslog
WHERE [Start/Return] != 0
GROUP BY [staffname]
```

Comment: This would work for staff who are currently away but then it doesn't give correct value for staff who have returned from sickness? Is there any way to have both? Sorry to be difficult  (ps, I substituted getdate for now() as access didn't recognise it.

Comment: If you want both just remove the where clause and condition "WHERE [Start/Return] != 0"

Comment: SELECT [staffname], DATEDIFF("d",min([date]),IIF(min([date])=max([date]),now(),max([date]))) AS [Days Sick]
FROM sicknesslog
WHERE [date]>(now()-7)
GROUP BY [staffname];

Comment: You don't need the difference between min([date]) and max([date]  that is the difference between starting date and maximum date value for some worker in a table. You need difference between min([date]) and current date, GETDATE() or in your case NOW().

Answer (score 1):

Note: this is `SQL Server` syntax. 
The idea:
1. The `a` table will have all employees latest absence starts and ends
2. Once we have this we're calculating the day difference in case the absence is "in range" (last 30 days in your example) if not we're using the `Dateadd(day, -30, GETDATE())` or `(now()-30)` from your example - same applies for end date - if the absence is still ongoing use the query's end date to determine number of days...(`now()`)

[Demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1a85f/2)

```
select distinct a.staffname, IsNULL(Datediff(DAY, 
   case when  a.LastAbsenceStarted between  Dateadd(day, -30, GETDATE()) and GETDATE() then a.LastAbsenceStarted  
   else Dateadd(day, -30, GETDATE()) End, case when a.LastAbsenceEnded is null then GETDATE() else a.LastAbsenceEnded End), 0) as absences
from

(
    SELECT [staffname], (select  max([date]) from sicknesslog s where s.staffname = ss.staffname and [start/return]  = 1)as [LastAbsenceStarted],
                (select  max([date]) from sicknesslog s where s.staffname = ss.staffname and [start/return]  = 0)as [LastAbsenceEnded]
    FROM sicknesslog ss
    GROUP BY [staffname]
    ) a  inner join sicknesslog b on a.staffname = b.staffname
where b.Date between Dateadd(day, -30, GETDATE()) and GETDATE()
```

Hope this will help you build your `Access` query accordingly.

Comment: Haha, wow. I'm sure that works beautifully in SQL server but I think I overestimated my ability to translate it for access. It's a bit beyond me. Is anyone else able to work this out?